# Global Messages in Magento CMS Page

Tags: magento

I have added mxpert login to the homepage CMS page of my Magento site. I would like to load Global Messages to this login, to show customers if they have an error while logging in.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using this:

```
<?php echo
    Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->
        setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(true))->getGroupedHtml() 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Magento provides mini login feature, which you can always use, irrespective of where the user is currently in. So in all the pages (including CMS pages), the user can login using the mini login feature.

Now in case any error occurs, Magento will by default redirect the user to the main login page, where the actual error will be shown to the user. So you will not need to change any of the basic flow of the Magento theme, which you are developing or changing.

Hope it helps.

---

**EDIT:-**
What Magento does (by default) is it stores all the messages (successes / errors / warnings) in a specific session array. It is get called in each & every page of the front-end using the following line of code:-
`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>`.
You can find the above line in almost all the page layouts (like "`1column.phtml`", "`2columns-left.phtml`", & so on) defined in the folder "`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/`". Also the above line of code implies that there should be a block named "`global_messages`" in one of the Layout XML files, unless it has been mistakenly tampered with.

Now the above briefing was necessary for understanding how the Magento system shows any sort of messages. So whenever any of these messages (if any exist) get shown in the front-end page, then the relevant session array removes / clears those message elements from its array.
But the main thing is that the messages should be shown in the proper page, where it's meant to be. If not, then whenever Magento finds the proper place of showing the messages, it will show up (in some inappropriate page). **And I suppose this is what is happening to you too.**

So it will be better if you can please check out the proper template file & accordingly the relevant layout page (amongst the pages listed in the folder "`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/`" like "`1column.phtml`", "`2columns-left.phtml`" & so on) for the following code:-
`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>`.

Comment: the problem that i don´t see the messages error in my CMS page, however if i put an error in login, refresh and don´t see anything, but i go to register, i see ol queues of error, because in this page load the global messages. any ideas???

Comment: i understand this, but i made new template for this page, the template name welcome.phtml, is diferent to another page, for this reason decide make this. and this page is create in CMS and i assign my new template, but this page don´t have a layout, how i can create this???? i try to add block of global messages in cms.xml but don´t work. thanks